# Using T-SQL REPLACE with wildcard lookup to replace field values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace

I have table with schema:

```
CREATE TABLE InvestorDetails
(
    [ID] INT PRIMARY KEY,
    [Created] DATETIME,
    [Updated] DATETIME,
    [ToEmail] VARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

Records in InvestorDetails look like the following:

```
1, 2017-01-01, 2017-02-02, ames@gmail.com;mark@gmail.com;tom@gmail.com;mitchel@gmail.com
2, 2017,01-02, 2017-02-02, ben@gmail.com;michael@gmail.com;mark@gmail.com
3, 2017-02-02, 2017,02-03, test@gmail.com;matthew@gmail.com;dan@gmail.com;jay@gmail.com;mark@gmail.com
```

I want to write a query that will go through and update each record in the table that has 'mark@gmail.com' in field 'ToEmail' with 'markTest@gmail.com'

So for example in record 1 above, I want it to look like:

```
1, 2017-01-01, 2017-02-02, ames@gmail.com;markTest@gmail.com;tom@gmail.com;mitchel@gmail.com
```

I can find the records with mark@gmail.com in 'EmailRecipients'using the following query:

```
SELECT I.ID, I.EmailRecipients
FROM InvestorDetails I
WHERE I.EmailRecipients LIKE '%mark@gmail.com%'
```

The tricky part is ensuring only the mark@gmail.com is changed, and the rest remains. I believe this can be achieved with TSQL REPLACE, but I'm having trouble writing the SQL, particularly what to use as the string_pattern and string_replacement parameters.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query

```
UPDATE InvestorDetails
SET EmailRecipients = 
       REPLACE(';' + EmailRecipients  + ';', ';mark@gmail.com;' , ';markTest@gmail.com;' )
WHERE EmailRecipients LIKE '%;mark@gmail.com;%'
```

This is made to ensure that mails that contains mark such as `drmark@gmail.com` are not updated.

If you want to remove the added leadin and trailing semicolons you can use the following query

You can use the following query

```
UPDATE InvestorDetails
SET EmailRecipients = 
       SUBSTRING(REPLACE(';' + EmailRecipients  + ';', ';mark@gmail.com;' , ';markTest@gmail.com;'),2, LEN( REPLACE(';' + EmailRecipients  + ';', ';mark@gmail.com;' , ';markTest@gmail.com;' ) - 2 )
WHERE EmailRecipients LIKE '%;mark@gmail.com;%' AND ISNULL(EmailRecipients,'') <> ''
```

Another query was provided by @MartinSmith in the comments

```
UPDATE InvestorDetails 
SET ToEmail = SUBSTRING(replaced, 2, LEN(replaced) -2) 
FROM InvestorDetails
    CROSS APPLY
(SELECT REPLACE(';'+ ToEmail + ';',';mark@gmail.com;' , ';markTest@gmail.com;')) CA(replaced) 
WHERE ToEmail LIKE '%mark@gmail.com%'
```

Comment: What will happen to the string “drmark@gmail.com;mark@gmail.com”?

Comment: Probably easiest way would be to just concatenate a leading and trailing semicolon to the list. Use that as the subject of the replace which also looks for item surrounded by leading and trailing semicolon then strip the first and last character off.

Comment: @MartinSmith check my answer, is this what you are trying ot say

Comment: Yep basically - My previous comment had a bug in it on the length so `UPDATE InvestorDetails
SET ToEmail = SUBSTRING(replaced, 2, LEN(replaced) -2)
FROM Investordetails
CROSS APPLY(SELECT REPLACE(';'+ ToEmail + ';',';mark@gmail.com;' , ';markTest@gmail.com;')) CA(replaced)
WHERE Emailcolumn LIKE '%mark@gmail.com%'`

Comment: @MartinSmith what is the difference between the old and new query?

Comment: It needs to use the length after replacement not before.

Comment: @MartinSmith i provided my old query in the answer, also your final query. thx a lot for good informations